# UI Testing of iOS 3rd Party applications - No Source Code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appium-ios, xcuitest

I'm working in the Aviation industry and part of my job is managing electronic flight bags (EFB). We rely on 3rd party applications such as `Ozrunways/Jepp FDPro` and therefore we don't have the source code or .ipa files to create UI tests through XCode.

There have been issues where updates to apps will get released with small bugs and we only find out via user reporting. I really don't wanna go down the road of creating a manual testing regime whereby each app is tested by humans pressing buttons on the device to ensure the UI/functionalities are the same.

Is there any way to automate this through the simulator or the device?

Note: I went down the appium path originally but realized without the .ipa file it's almost impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can run tests of Apple and 3rd party apps on the devices as well as Apple apps on Simulator by using `XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier:_)`API. This way you can keep only your UI tests target, without any target app in target settings.

Example: https://github.com/rzakhar/xctest-assignment

Comment: What if the app is not installed and you have only the .app file or .ipa file of the app ?

Comment: Install the app first, then use an API mentioned before

Comment: How do I install the app ? I want to avoid manual app installation as I have to run these tests on CI.

Comment: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller

Comment: Nice answer, we should accept it. @RomanZakharov just out of curiosity, how did you create that kind of Xcode project? It seems that we don't need to create a mock app to trigger the target app.

Comment: @RomanZakharov I did try to create a blank Xcode project and add test target to it. But got error `NSInternalInconsistencyException: No target application path specified via test configuration`

Comment: Did you use XCUIElement() without specifying the bundle identifier?

Comment: @RomanZakharov It seems that it's not identifier related. My code is pretty simple, just `let app = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.reminders")` and `app.launch()` . It sounds like I had missed some configurations of Xcode.

Comment: If you share it on Github, I will probably check it